# How to determine the column name to read value from a list in c# at run time?

Tags: winforms, generics, c#-2.0

I have a datagridview (DGV) which contains some columns and a generic list which contains the focus information for all those columns available in the DGV. Now when I enter e cell in DGV, I want to get it's focus information from the list in a string variable. I am receiving the DGVs **currentCell** and **fieldName** (DGVs column name for which I want to load focus info) as input parameters. Below is my code:

```
private Rectangle GetFocusSettingsForField(string fieldName, DataGridViewCell currentCell)
        {
            NA27Bo bo = new NA27Bo();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            string projectId = dgvEntryVerify["ProjectId", currentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string batchId = dgvEntryVerify["BatchId", currentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string imageId = dgvEntryVerify["ImageId", currentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string noOnImage = dgvEntryVerify["NumberOnImage", currentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            int serialNo = Convert.ToInt32(dgvEntryVerify["SerialNumber", currentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

            PropertyInfo[] properties = bo.GetType().GetProperties();
            string actualFieldName = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                if (properties[i].Name.Contains(fieldName + "Focus"))
                {
                    actualFieldName = properties[i].Name;
                }
            }

            // Here I want to get the data from property "actualFieldName" of the list
            //string value = data from property "actualFieldName" of the list
}
```

I am using VS2012, C#, Winforms but Framework 2.0 (framework can't be changed).

Comment: The question is little bit unclear. Are you asking how you can retrieve value of the bo instance property based on the property name? For example bo.BatchIdFocus based on "BatchIdFocus"?

Comment: Yes...However, I have solved this using this..... string fieldCoordinate = (String)focus.GetType().GetProperty(String.Format("{0}Focus", fieldName)).GetValue(focus, null) ?? String.Empty;

Comment: Why did you not simply use a `Dictionary`?